# Lebesgue Premeasure via Transfinite Induction

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, ordinals, transfinite-induction

If $I=[a,b)$ we write $|I|=b-a$ for the length of $I$. Given a theorem of Caratheodory, the tricky part in showing the existence of Lebesgue measure is this:

**Lemma** If $[0,1)$ is the disjoint union of a countable collection $(I_j)$ of half-open intervals then $\sum_j|I_j|=1$.

It's easy to conclude that this is easier than it really is, if, as for example in
[Easy proof for existence of Lebesgue-premeasure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407186/easy-proof-for-existence-of-lebesgue-premeasure/1407199?noredirect=1#comment2869173_1407199), one assumes that we can order the $I_j$ in such a way that $I_{j+1}$ lies to the right of $I_j$. The actual arrangement of the $I_j$ within $[0,1)$ can be much more complicated than that. Let's call the failed argument the "naive" proof.

The lemma is more or less Lemma 1.15 in Folland *Real Analysis* (Folland does it for general Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures). Folland calls the proof "remarkably fussy", which seems right. He says that the reason for the remarkable fussiness is that the arrangement of the intervals within $[0,1)$ can be order-isomorphic to any countable ordinal.

His point is that a countable ordinal can be complicated. I read this comment once and said to myself a countable ordinal is not that bad. In fact one can fix the naive proof, using a simple transfinite induction. (And we don't need to actually mention ordinals *per se* at all.)

**Question** Anyone ever seen the proof below?

**Proof of the Lemma** Given two disjoint intervals $I$ and $J$, write $I<J$ if $x<y$ for every $x\in I$ and $y\in J$.

Suppose that $[0,1)$ is the disjoint union of the half-open intervals $I_j$. First we note that the $I_j$ are well-ordered (under the order on intervals we just defined).

Indeed, if we had a decreasing sequence of $I_j$ they would accumulate at some point $x$. But there exists $k$ so $x\in I_k=[a_k,b_k)$, and hence disjointness shows our sequence of intervals cannot accumulate at $x$ after all.

Just for the sake of notation, we want there to be a rightmost interval. So add the interval $[1,2)$ to the collection, so now the union is $[0,2)$. The letters $I$ and $J$ will always refer to intervals in our collection.

We claim that for every $J$ we have $$\left|\bigcup_{I\le J}I\right|=\sum_{I\le J}|I|\quad(*).$$

If not, suppose that $J$ is the *smallest* counterexample: For every $J'<J$, ($*$) holds with $J'$ in place of $J$. Then $$\bigcup_{I<J}I=\bigcup_{J'<J}\left(\bigcup_{I\le J'}I\right),$$so
$$\left|\bigcup_{I<J}I\right|=\sup_{J'<J}\left|\bigcup_{I\le J'}I\right|
=\sup_{J'<J}\sum_{I\le J'}|I|=\sum_{I<J}|I|,$$and we're done (add $J$ to the union on the left and $|J|$ to the sum on the right).

So ($*$) holds for every $J$, and setting $J=[1,2)$ shows precisely that $\sum|I_j|=1$.

Comment: Drive-by downvote - one wonders what the problem is...

Comment: the problem is that he has a much simpler proof than the book and wants to know if he's right . looks ok to me.

Comment: @user254665 I think you missed who wrote what. I'm the OP and I also wrote that comment. I wasn't wondering what the OP's problem was - got no problem, I know it's right. I got a downvote - I was wondering what problem the downvoter saw here.

Comment: Nice post. Maybe it would be worthwhile to point out that completeness of $\Bbb{R}$ is used in an essential way to show that your intervals are well-ordered. Because my usual way of showing that "alternative" ways of proving countable additivity do not work is that they do not use completeness and thus would also work for $\Bbb{Q}$ instead of $\Bbb{R}$ (with a suitable interpretation of intervals etc.).

Comment: The completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ is used in an essential way to show that your intervals are well-ordered by the order induced by the usual $<$ order in $\mathbb{R}$.  HOWEVER, a more subtle question is where  after that point in the proof, is it used that the well-ordering is this specific one (induced by by the usual $<$ order in $\mathbb{R}$).  In any well-ordering we can add $[1,2)$ to greater than all the other intervals. The answer is: it is used to have that $\bigcup_{I\le J}I$  and $\bigcup_{I< J}I$ are intervals. And that is also key to make the proof work.

Comment: @Ramiro Exactly. Those things being intervals is crucial. This is related to what strikes me as cool about it - it really is "just like" the wrong naive proof where we assume $I_j<I_{j+1}$. We just go along from left to right adding one more interval at a time... takes some countable ordinal number of steps but it really is just this one then the next one, then eventually we're done. I can't complain at your skepticism about the words "simple and straightforward" elsewhere, since you were so enthusiastic. But it _does_ seem at least "natural"... just add em up.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is "natural". It is a very nice and interesting proof.

Comment: This sounds like the *Lebesgue chain* notion that was used roughly during the mid 1910s to the mid 1930s. You can find a lot of references by googling the phrase, but perhaps the best place to begin is the 1925 3rd edition of Volume I of Hobson's **The Theory Of Functions Of A Real Variable** (doesn't seem to be freely available on the internet) and Hildebrandt's 1926 Bull. AMS paper [*The Borel theorem and its generalizations*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183487130) (see p. 429). The idea of a half-open interval wasn't used, but I believe the same underlying idea is there.

Comment: I should have said *the 1927 3rd edition of Volume I of Hobson's*. (I didn't notice this until later, too late to correct my original comment.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since you are the creator of the (transfinite-induction) tag, I though it might be polite that I have started [a discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28242/on-the-tags-transfinite-induction-and-transfinite-recursion) related to this tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am? Don't recall creating that tag...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich As far as I can tell, this was the first question having this tag, more details [can be found here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44017580#44017580). (Maybe we will see in a while whether you get taxonomist badge when the tag gets 50th question - that would be a confirmation.) In any case, the main point was that the tag-creator might be interested in discussion about the tag, which is why I posted the above comment.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, I wasn't disputing the idea that I created the tag, just don't recall. That was years ago, before I had any idea that things are sometimes controversial around here...

Comment: I also came up with this during my second real analysis class. Transfinite recursion is indeed very intuitive. But could you explain the first supremum in the third from last line? My thought was to discuss the successor case and limit case separately, and in the limit case take a countable cofinal sequence and use $\sigma$-additivity.