# How to show this cover of $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't cover $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, rational-numbers

Let $\{q_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ and define $\mathcal{O} = \{I_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ being

$$I_n = \left(q_n - \frac{1}{2^n}, q_n + \frac{1}{2^n}\right).$$

It is obvious that $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I want to show this is not a cover of $\mathbb{R}$. One possible way that I've already seem is to see that the total length of the intervals is $2\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}=2$ while the length of $\mathbb{R}$ is $+\infty$.

Although this works, I'm trying to find *another way* to prove this result. One thing that is intuitively clear is that if $n\to \infty$ then the intervals shrink as small as desired around the rational midpoint, since $1/2^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. I thought on using this to show that there is some irrational in the "middle" of two such $I_n$ for large enough $n$, but I don't even know how to start this.

Anyway, how can I prove this result without using the measure argument? Is my idea correct? If so, how can it be made rigorous?

Comment: Depending on how the rationals are ordered, it seems dangerous to talk about "the middle" of consecutive $I_n$; they could potentially be extremely close together, or extremely far apart. I wonder how to get around the unknown ordering... (+1)

Comment: The problem is that for 2 such $I_n$, the middle contains infinitely many more of these intervals.  So you don't know whether these intervals in the middle cover every irrational.

Comment: It covers the interval $[0,10]$, so there is a finite subcover that covers $[0,10]$. The rest requires little.

Comment: @pjs36: The ordering of the intervals can be complicated, but this can be handled by transfinite induction.  See [this nice argument by David C. Ullrich](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408533/lebesgue-premeasure-via-transfinite-induction)

Answer (score 5):

Let us work with the closed interval $[0,2]$, let $\{q_n\}$ be a enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,2]$, and define 
$$I_n := \bigg(q_n -\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, q_n+ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\bigg)\bigcap [0,2]$$
then $\{I_n\}$ is an open cover of the rationals in the space $[0,2]$.

(I used  $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ so that the sum of the length is $1$, there is a small typo in your post.)

Since $I_n^c$ the complement in $[0,2]$ is closed, define 
$$C_k =\bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^k I_n\bigg)^c = \bigcap_{n=1}^k I_n^c,$$
we see that each $C_k$ is non-empty, closed, and the sequence $\{C_k\}$ is nested. Therefore, using nested set theorem (Cantor's intersection theorem)
$$\text{ there exists } x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n^c \neq \emptyset$$
by construction, $x$ is irrational, and therefore $\{I_n\}$ doesn't cover all irrational numbers.

For the argument in $\mathbb{R}$, you can first restrict to the compact subspace $[0,2]$, where your open cover of $\mathbb{Q}$ would become $I_n\cap [0,2]$ and the same argument would follow.

Comment: How do we see that $C_k$ is nonempty?  That seems to be the hard part.

Comment: @NateEldredge, the union of the first $k$ of the $I_n$’s has measure at most $1$ in all cases. So its complement has measure at least $1$.

Comment: @Lubin: But I thought the idea was to avoid using any facts about measure.  Anyway, I've posted an answer that will show that $C_k$ is nonempty.

Comment: I don’t see that adding up the lengths of finitely many intervals can be thought of as measure theory, @NateEldredge. We could step outdoors to come to blows over this, I suppose.

Comment: @Lubin: I agree it's not really measure theory, but it's not completely obvious either, at least not to me.  I had to think for a while the first time I had to prove the lemma in my answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge The argument for finite $k$ and intervals can be done without "measure theory" argument, but as you said this indeed is something we might learn at the beginning of studying Lebesgue measure theory (as in Royden's Real analysis).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is kind of cheating, since it's really just extracting the essential pieces of measure theory needed to prove this.  But it's self contained and doesn't need to use the word "measure".

Fix a closed interval such as $[0,2]$ whose length is at least as long as the sum of the lengths of your intervals $I_n$ (as currently formulated, that sum is 2 instead of 1). By compactness (as suggested in Xiao's answer), it is sufficient to show that no *finite* subset of $\mathcal{O}$ covers $[0,2]$.  This can be done by means of the following elementary lemma:

**Lemma**. For every $n$, every interval $[a,b]$, and every set of $n$ intervals $(a_1, b_1), \dots, (a_n, b_n)$  such that $[a,b] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n (a_i, b_i)$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)>b-a$.

*Proof*.  Proceed by induction on $n$.  The base case $n=1$ is easy.  Now suppose the claim holds for $n-1$.  Let $[a,b]$ be an interval covered by $(a_1, b_1), \dots, (a_n, b_n)$.  One of the intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ must contain the point $b$; without loss of generality suppose it's $(a_n, b_n)$.  If $a_n < a$ we are done, since then $(a_n, b_n)$ covers $[a,b]$ and we invoke the $n=1$ case to see that $b-a < b_n-a_n \le \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)$.  Otherwise, if $a_n \ge a$, then the intervals $(a_1, b_1), \dots, (a_{n-1}, b_{n-1})$ cover $[a, a_n]$.  So by the inductive hypothesis, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (b_i - a_i) > a_n - a$.  Now adding $b_n - a_n$ to both sides and noting that $b_n > b$ we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_i - a_i) > (a_n - a) + (b_n - a_n) = b_n - a > b - a$$
as desired.

(This is essentially the proof that shows that the Lebesgue outer measure of an interval $[a,b]$ is $b-a$, which is a key step in the construction of Lebesgue measure.)

Let me also put in an advertisement for a pretty approach by David C. Ullrich in [Lebesgue Premeasure via Transfinite Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408533/lebesgue-premeasure-via-transfinite-induction), which uses completeness instead of compactness and so dodges the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge. I might be wrong, but this proof seems even simpler than the proof using Cantor's intersection theorem. In truth, since the series of lenghts is absolutely convergent, any reordering of the terms will yield the same sum which is $2$. Because of that any partial sum must be less or equal to $2$. This means that any collection of finite intervals has total length less or equal to $2$ and by that lemma it can't cover $[0,2]$, because to do that it would need to be of length greater than $2$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1620696: Right.  The "Cantor's intersection theorem" argument given in Xiao's answer is essentially the same as what I indicated by saying "by compactness".  Cantor's intersection theorem is exactly what you get by taking the statement "every open cover has a finite subcover" and taking complements and the contrapositive.