# Reordering of a countable number of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have the disjoint sets $\{(1,2],(3,4],(0,1],(2,3],(4,5]\}$. I can reorder these in such a way that I would like to call *increasing*: $\{(0,1],(1,2],(2,3],(3,4],(4,5]\}$.

Similarly, suppose I have a collection of sets $\{(n,n+1]:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Can I reorder these in such a way to also achieve the same result.

I am asking this in relation to the answer given in [Easy proof for existence of Lebesgue-premeasure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407186/easy-proof-for-existence-of-lebesgue-premeasure?rq=1) to prove countable additivity of the Lebesgue pre-measure. The OP claims he can reorder disjoint intervals of the real line in such a way to produce a telescoping sum. I cannot see what is wrong with the examples given in the solution to this question, nor the approach taken by the OP.

This is the example they gave:

"Simple example: Say $I_n=[1-1/n,1-1/(n+1))$, so $[0,1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$. *Those* intervals can be ordered the way you want, in fact they already are ordered that way.

But now say $J_n=[2-1/n,2-1/(n+1))$. So $[0,2)=\bigcup_{n=1}^
\infty I_n \cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty J_n$. You can't "reorder" the collection of all the $I_n$ *and* the $J_n$ the way you want."

Comment: The interval $J_1 = [1, 3/2)$ has infinitely many predecessors. The order type of $\{ I_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\} \cup \{ J_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is not $\omega$, which would be necessary for a reordering as posited in the question, it is $\omega + \omega$. And as the answer goes on to elaborate, one can have a family of intervals with much wilder order type.

Comment: Could you expand on this? I read somewhere that the disjoint union of countable sets is also countable so a reordering could be done in light of this surely?

Comment: Yes, a countable union of countable sets is countable (unless one works with the assumption that choice fails, then it might be uncountable), but that's not the problem here. The problem is order type. For the argument the OP made in the question it must be possible to index the intervals in such a way that $I_k$ lies to the left of $I_{k+1}$ for all $k$, and that means for every $I_k$ there are only finitely many intervals lying to the left of it. That isn't the case for the family consisting of the $I_n$ and the $J_n$, every $J_n$ has infinitely many intervals to the left of it.

Comment: David C. Ullrich shows that a variant of the idea works [in this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408533/lebesgue-premeasure-vis-transfinite-induction), but instead of ordinary induction one must use induction over an arbitrary countable well-ordered set.

Comment: Wow, now I see why the argument fails! Thank you, upvote for the comment.